# JSON link in amp-list is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-amp

I'm trying to load dynamic data to my amp page. For testing I tried one of the examples(amp-list) from google playground. 
But the server I'm currently on is http. AMP requires https link for the json file to work. So I moved the file to another https server. But when I give the https link of the json file from the external server, the data isnt loading. 
When I use the same json file from the google-amp server the data loads perfectly. 
Please help.